# I’m back in graduate school and I’m struggling with writing APA. What’s the best way to learn?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing

What is the best way of learning APA writing if you have never written in that format?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This APA? https://www.amazon.ca/Publication-Manual-American-Psychological-Association/dp/143383216X/

Comment: As it stands, this question is much too broad. Do you struggle with the APA citation style? Google for a brief summary of the most important points and beyond that search for whatever comes up when it comes up. Or are you unclear about the internal structure your paper should have? Then either take an introductory course at your university on the subject of scientific writing or get a book that explains scientific writing for your field.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend with starting with a APA template for your writing program -- like MS Word or Google Docs. There seem to be quite a few to chose from on university websites.

Then, don't focus on writing your first drafts to conform to the APA style guides.  Worrying about syntax and style sap the creative and intellectual process.

### Write the best papers you can, then edit the papers to conform to the APA style guides.

If you've other papers you've written in your undergraduate, you can edit them to use the APA style.  As a way to learn. There seem to be lots and lots of  guidelines and tutorial on mastering that style -- many are listed in answers to this near duplicate question on Writing@SE [How can a practical learner get up to speed on APA quickly?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/5484/how-can-a-practical-learner-get-up-to-speed-on-apa-quickly?rq=1)